# How to Find toolstripButton inside toolstrip in a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I used this code below to Enable/Disable Button Control inside my usercontol on my Form which works perfect.

```
var btnAdd = this.userControlCommonTask1.Controls.Find("btnAdd", true);
btnAdd[0].Enabled = true;
```

But when i use toostrip(toolstrip1) with buttons (btnAdd,btnEdit,btndelete etch..) and use my code above

[image]

I got:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I tried this one but it only works in toolstrip.

```
       var btnAdd = this.userControlCommonTask1.Controls.Find("toolstrip1", true);
        btnAdd[0].Enabled = true;
```

Thanks in Regards

Comment: Though my comment is a little off the track but yet I wanted to know that assuming you are using a toolstrip inside an usercontrol, after you add items to the toolstrip, if you copy the whole usercontrol and paste it somewhere else then is it preserving the items of the toolstrip? If yes then how do you achieve it? Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already Solve my Problem:

```
        var toolstrip1 = this.userControlCommonTask1.Controls.Find("toolstrip1", true);
        var toolstrip1Items = toolstrip1[0] as ToolStrip; <-- set to toolstrip control

        var btnRead = toolstrip1Items.Items.Find("btnRead", true); <--get BtnRead on toolstrip Item.Find
        btnRead[0].Enabled = false; <--disable/Enable btn
```

This can be a reference for other Developers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try a 0 instead of 1 your array is zero based

Answer (score 0):

Toolstrip is another usercontrol. Try make a reference to it and then find it's child controls

ie. ctlTooolStrip.Controls.Find("BtnAdd",true);

Also try toolStrip.Items

Comment: I can see you have solved the problems with toolstrip.items. Long after I posted this. !!!